# Is there a way to pass a property of a node in AEM to its sling:resourceType and access that property using sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly, aem-6

I have a node created with sling:resourceType property which has path pointing to a sightly component, where in, this component is used to populate drop down values in a dialog, dynamically.

In my dialog, I have multiple drop downs which I need to dynamically populate.

For every drop down I need to access the same component, but I need to populate different values for each of them.

So is there a way to pass a parameter/a key to that component, from the node which accesses it, so that I will be able to read the parameter in my components html?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information. I find your use case somewhat difficult to visualise without an example of the content structure and maybe a piece of the dialog (be it a picture or a piece of xml/json)

Comment: Hi I am doing an implementation using a datasource, similar to the article here https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-granite-datasource.html.

Comment: http://adobeaemclub.com/implement-datasource-for-drop-down-using-sightly-aem-6-1/ this is one more link which I am referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why would you need a component to achieve this, You could define different datasource (`com.adobe.granite.ui.components.ds.DataSource`) implementation and based on the your dropdown invoke these datasource.

Refer to datasource Java Docs [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/ui/components/ds/DataSource.html), for sample implementation in touch UI refer to article [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-granite-datasource.html) and in [AEM ACS COMMON](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/generic-lists.html), it should work with ClassicUI as well with little modification.

In case you wish to proceed with the existing approach, there is no such straight way to pass one of the component property to the resourceType of the component. What you could do if use selectors with the component inclusion to pass those property values as selectors.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I am using data source component similar to the touch Ui article link you have shared above. As you mentioned, I can achieve this by creating separate datasource for each of my dropdown values. But I wanted a single datasource and pass some parameter/a key to that datasource.

Comment: Then y do u need to pass property? You can have ny number of datasources nd you can associate them with dropdowns using listeners

Comment: Also could you please share some references on the selectors use which you have mentioned above, as I am not aware of that?

Comment: I don't want to have n number of datasources doing the same logic. I will be having a JSON, where in my key would be the dropdown node parameter, and in the data source component I will just get that key, parse my JSON and populate the values corresponding to it. So I am interested to know if there is a way to pass the property to my data source.

Comment: Look at the implementation at - https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/content/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/acs-commons/components/utilities/genericlist/datasource/datasource.jsp, the path is additional property specified along with datasource - https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/generic-lists.html

Comment: Thanks! The git hub reference which you have provided worked.